# Getting to bound data in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angular to get binding back from a template?

In other words, if I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
      <div>{{item.state}}</div>
</div>
```

would it be possible to change the item's state by clicking on it, because the repeated div would "remember" what item it was built from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `ng-click` directive to trigger a method on the current scope:

```
// In your view's controller:
function MyCtrl($scope, MyList) {
  // You probably have something like that already to
  // populate your list, using a $resource or $http GET call.
  // Here I use a $resource which would be defined on your module.
  $scope.list = MyList.query()

  $scope.setState = function(state) {
    // "this" refers to the current scope
    this.item.state = state
  }
}

// And in your view:
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  <div ng-click="setState('whatever')">{{item.state}}</div>
</div>
```

Or you can simply set an expression such as `ng-click="item.state='whatever'"` directly on the div, although this is less testable - only in end-to-end tests - and less flexible, say you want to introduce validation or something).

HTH